# Error occurred when configuring project ':app' (org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException) and ERROR ASCII also found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I was trying to build my project and I got some errors in the project's gradle file specifically the build.gradle(app) file. When trying to build the project, I got the following errors:

1) **org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'**

2) **ERROR: ASCII also found**

Also, I can't view my UI designs. I have been battling with this error for a few days and I really need help getting it fixed. This is my build.gradle(app) file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.onebookingsystem.obs"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 16
        versionName "1.1.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        compile('com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.0.0') {
            transitive = true;
            exclude module: 'payumoney-sdk'
        }

        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        //noinspection GradleCompatible
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
        compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
        compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
//        compile 'com.matthew-tamlin:sliding-intro-screen:3.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
//    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.0.1'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
        compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        //firebase
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
        compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'

        compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.0'

        //sms verify catcher
//    compile 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.2'
//    compile 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.21'

        //spinner design
//    compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.9'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
You would need to change all to implementation example

```
 androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',)
```

next you will need to update your app dependencies to and your build tools api 28 or later.
I noticed you're using different versions of firebase which will definitely crash your app.

> Also, I can't view my UI designs.

The latest firebase dependencies are on androidX, you need to migrate your project to androidX . [image: as shown below] [image: then]

Comment: You need to have compileSdk set to at least 28 in your module build.gradle to migrate to AndroidX.The gradle plugin version in your project build.gradle file needs to be set to at least com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0 in order to migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: the above error box appears when I click migrate option

Comment: Is I need to change all the 'compile' files to 'implementation' files?

Comment: yes,the keyword compile is no longer used.change to implementation.but first upgrade your material dependencies to v 28 then refactor